# How to stop a pull request being closed with unmerged commits

Tags: git, github, githooks, git-workflow

Could anyone suggest a way of stopping/informing a user that there is an open pull request on github on a branch they are trying to delete?

We currently use the following branches `master`,`rc`,`hotfix` and `prod` to represent the various environments.  When we have a `hotfix` branch that we want to promote to `prod` we delete the `prod` branch and force push the `hotfix` branch at the point it was built.  Generally this will work as expected.  However in the example I am questioning we have had cases where we deploy the `hotfix` to production with a partial set of changes (`HEAD` of the `hotfix` branch is not what is being deployed.  And in some cases these are still awaiting code review in the form of a pull request for further outstanding work.

What I am looking for is a way of informing the user when they are trying to delete the hotfix branch that the `HEAD` was not what we deployed to production and more importantly that there are outstanding Merge Requests.

We have had pull request being auto closed for no reason other than the remote branch has been deleted, when this is not needed and will simply need to be recreated from the `prod` branch and the request reopened.  This is due to our git workflow that we delete these branches as described above, but ideally would allow them to remain open for the pull request to be completed and then a subsequent deployment made and the branch only gets deleted when there is no outstanding work.

Answer (score 2):

On which system are you working?
gitHub?
stash?

The problem is this:
When you open a pull request it attached to a certain branch and the changes are "compared" to the commit id of the branch you worked on.

When you delete the branch you delete the reference to the "root" of the changes so git has no clue what to compare it to. your changes re stored in the branch that you set in the pull request. now that you have deleted the branch you delete the changes. You cannot expect git to "know" that you want him to save the changes for you.

To summarize:
The origin of the pull request is the branch with the changes you made. once you delete the branch you delete your changes and you cannot expect git to save them for future use.

Comment: Sorry jsexpert I may not of explained our workflow correctly.  I have edited my question accordingly.